# Spearman correlation and Pearson correlation

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, spearman-rho

If $X$ and $Y$ has the Spearman correlation $r_s=1$, is it possible that the Pearson correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is 0?

Answer (score 2):

Yes if by $1$ and $0$ you mean $\approx 1$ and $\approx 0$. Here is one example in R with a stupid outlier

```
x=c(1:1000)
y=c(1:999,-100000)

> cor(x,y,method="spearman")
[1] 0.994006
> cor(x,y,method="pearson")
[1] 0.03571434
```

Comment: I suspect you could find an example with $r_s\approx 1$ and $r_p=0$ but not $r_s= 1$ and $r_p\approx 0$

Comment: Can we construct a monotone function $Y=f(X)$ such that $f$ is monontone, But $Cov(X,Y)=0$?

Comment: @mathbeginner What do you think?

Comment: I mean that if $x$ and $y$ has the strictly monotone relationship, for example, y=x^3, can we have cov(x,y)=0

Comment: A Spearman correlation of 1 implies that all data lie on a rising monotonic curve (in fact on many such curves). I can't see that is compatible with Pearson correlation zero.

Comment: @Nick Cox,you mean if $r_s=1$ or $r_s=-1$, we can conclude that $r_p\neq 0$? But How to prove it?

Comment: What kind of proof do you need? A rising (or as you say falling) curve isn't compatible with a zero slope to a regression, which is what is implied by correlation zero. The proof is geometric or spatial.

Comment: I mean by the formula of computing the Spearman correlation $r_s = 1- \frac{6\Sigma d^2}{n(n^2 -1)}=1$, how to derive that $r_p\neq 0$,where $r_p=\frac{\sum ^n _{i=1}(x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sqrt{\sum ^n _{i=1}(x_i - \bar{x})^2} \sqrt{\sum ^n _{i=1}(y_i - \bar{y})^2}}$

Comment: Sorry, but wanting algebra here seems wrong-headed and I don't have any inclination to try it, or perhaps even the ability to do it. Consider a different problem as an analogue:  Take two distinct points in the plane. Then only one straight line can be drawn through the points. That should be obvious on just thinking about it (playing with pen and paper is fine), but if you want something more rigorous I can't supply it. More positively put, the rest of our understanding of correlation helps: a zero correlation implies a fit y = a + 0 x  and no such fit is possible with a monotonic tendency.

Comment: a zero correlation implies a fit y = a + 0 x? If $X$ has a standard normal distribution, and $y=x^2$, $cov(x,y)=0$, but $y\neq a+0x$.

Comment: The **fit from a linear regression** (with one predictor) is what was stated. Clearly the real relation is, as stated in your comment, a quadratic, but the correlation will be zero and your best linear fit is a flat line.

Comment: @mathbeginner The formula $r_S = 1 - \frac{6\sum d^2}{n(n^2 -1)}$ only applies if there are no tied ranks. If there **are** tied ranks, you apply the formula for Pearson's $r$ to the ranks of the data.

Comment: @Alexis Many people apply that formula after using a convention that tied values are assigned the same rank such that the sum of ranks is conserved. So ties for ranks 2 and 3 are both assigned rank 2.5 and ties for ranks 2, 3, 4 are all assigned rank 3. I guess the small print is about the sampling distribution of Spearman if ties are present. Personally I almost never care about significance testing for correlations of any kind. They are just indicators of kind and strength of relationship to be seen in relation to scatter plots and to be modelled appropriately.

Comment: @NickCox My comment was not about the convention for assigning tied ranks, it was for how to calculate $r_S$. Many folks say the $1 - \frac{6\sum d^2}{n(n^2-1)}$ formula is not accurate when ties are present (which is a common enough fact in nonparametric statistics: ties require further calculation). My understanding is that Pearson's formula gives a different result when ties are accounted for.